# Extended Ascii characters in Code::Blocks C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, extended-ascii

I'm trying to use extended Ascii codes in a console application using C++ and Code::Blocks (character codes greater than 128). http://www.asciitable.com/
The console shows a question mark inside a diamond.

I tried so far:

```
char myChar = 200;
cout << myChar;

cout << static_cast<char>(200);
```

Comment: Extended ASCII does not exist. State your desired encoding and also set your console to use said encoding.

Comment: If we want to call it extended ascii then we can. So there!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the problem is, there are *many* "extended ASCII" encodings.  Refer to [a similar question with better answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618332/c-extended-ascii-characters).

Comment: What you have in your link is [codepage 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).  I recommend reading [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), by the co-creator of this website, in order to slightly increase your knowledge on character encodings.

Comment: Let's say I want to use UTF-8 encoding and print characters in the console. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

char can't hold the whole character set

use **unsigned char** instead.

```
unsigned char myChar = 200;
cout << myChar << endl;
```

a **char** is generally a **signed char**.
it can hold values from -128 to 127.   ASCII fits nicely in 0 to 127, so **char** is reasonable when working with ASCII.

For the non-ASCII characters 128 to 255, you need something bigger.
**unsigned char** can store values from 0 to 255.  That covers the whole character set.
It's just what you need.

There are other things to research. You can read about unicode.  But **unsigned char** should get you around your current issue.